# HTTPS / SSL only site on Piranha

Tags: piranha-cms

I am attempting to integrate Piranha into an existing MVC5 based site which is hosted on https only. Every time I attempt to preview a post however it always chucks out a http version - how can I force it to always use https?

Answer (score 0):

The preview URL is generate by a call to this helper method:

https://github.com/PiranhaCMS/Piranha/blob/master/Core/Piranha/WebPages/WebPiranha.cs#L174

which unfortunately doesn't take the current protocol into account. I've added an issue at GitHub for you here:

https://github.com/PiranhaCMS/Piranha/issues/423

If you want to update it right away you can get the full source code from github. Or even better, make a fork, update it and send a pull request :)

Regards

Håkan